# React native animation with interpolating not working

Tags: react-native, animation, string-interpolation

I have onboarding and dot component . I want to use opacity animation with interpolate on dots. But it is not working. Do I use onScroll in a wrong way or what ? Thanks to any help

```
const Onboarding = () => {
  const { width } = useOrientation();
  const scrollX = new Animated.Value(0);
   const onScroll = (event: any) => {
    Animated.event([{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { x: scrollX } } }]);
  };
 return (
    <Box flex={1} backgroundColor="mainBackground">
      <Box flex={3}>
        <Animated.ScrollView onScroll={onScroll} horizontal>
          {slides.map((data, index) => (
            <Slide key={index} data={data} {...{ index, scrollX }}
            />
          ))}
        </Animated.ScrollView>
      </Box>

      <Box
        flex={1}
       
      >
        {slides.map((_, index) => (
          <Dot key={index + 1} currentIndex={divide(scrollX, width)} {...{ index }}
          />
        ))}
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
};
const Dot = ({currentIndex,index}:DotProps) => {

  const opacity = interpolate(currentIndex,{
    inputRange:[index-1,index,index+1],
    outputRange:[0.5,1,0.5],
    extrapolate:Extrapolate.CLAMP,
    
  })
  return (
    <Animated.View
      style={{ opacity, backgroundColor: "#2CB9B0",width: 8,height: 8,borderRadius: 4
      }}
    />
  );
};
```